# Explicit template specialization in g++ causing troubles

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++

I've got the problem converting this piece of code to g++ from MSVC:

```
#include <unordered_map>
class A
{
    template <class T> class B;

    template<>
    class A::B<int>
    {

    };

    std::unordered_map<int, long, B<int>> m_Map;
};
```

Sure thing this is not standard c++, while VS still allows it GCC (g++) throws an error "Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope".  Now I make it c++ compliant following the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization:

```
#include <unordered_map>

class A
{
    template <class T> class B;
    template <> class B<int>;
    std::unordered_map<int, long, B<int>> m_Map;
};

template<>
class A::B<int>
{
    std::size_t operator()(int const& n) const {
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Alas, now VS gives me an error

```
Error   3   error C2079: 'std::_Hash_oper1<true,_Hasher>::_Hashobj' uses undefined class 'A::B<int>'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xhash
```

and

```
 Error  2   error C2139: 'A::B<int>' : an undefined class is not allowed as an argument to compiler intrinsic type trait '__is_empty'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\type_traits
```

So, unordered map definetely doesn't want to work with what it consideres an "undefined class". Even though I forward-declared it.
Does anyone has a clue what is it all about? Thank you.

Comment: A simple fix would be to make `class B` not be declared within `A` in the first place

Comment: Thank you, this works, you may publish as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard library containers can't be declared with incomplete types as the contained types. This causes undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required (meaning that some compilers may appear to accept it, and some may reject it or behave strangely at runtime).

You'll have to use a hash table from a different library (e.g.boost) that does support incomplete type, or redesign the code.

A simple fix would be to make class `B` not be declared within `A` in the first place

Comment: I think it's fairly unlikely that there's an implementation that supports incomplete *hashers*.

Comment: They are using the incomplete type `B<int>` as the third template parameter - the hasher. Which understandably breaks since implementations will almost certainly store the hasher directly (likely wrapped in some EBO-enabling machinery).